# Orientation Woes

Tags: physics, 3d, rotations

new to the forum :-)

I have a challenge and require some assistance. I am building a game within a creation game/toolset available on the PS4. I am building a simple flight model which accounts for angle of attack, effectively detecting the pitch / angle along the x axis in order to determine if the plane should decelerate or accelerate. In the case where it is pointed down, it should accelerate due to gravity and vice versa. Herein begins the problem! The tool contains a built in function to sense the orientation localised to the object. From what I understand the values generated are based on axis angle orientation and there is no built in code to change this. Using this formula, the calculation reads correctly when travelling in the original direction of the object, with the x axis showing accurate results based on the pitch. As soon as the object deviates from the original flight path, the angles shown do not calculate as expected. I have read up on Euler angles and believe this is what I need to calculate, however I would like to understand if this conversion is even possible based on the data I have available. I have a simple x, y and z angle based on axis angle representation. Pardon my ignorance however it has been some time since I delved into the depths of mathematics!

Comment: Set aside the acceleration for a moment; how do you know where the path of the aircraft will go next in $(x,y,z)$ coordinates?  If you have an answer to that, you can work out the acceleration due to gravity without worrying about any orientation angles at all.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is potentially an interesting and answerable question but we need more precise information. Please [eidt] the question to tell us just what input data you have and what output data you need, with a labelled diagram. Tell us too what your tools can do for you in addition to ordinary arithmetic and trigonometry.

Comment: On further though, it's not clear to me what you mean by "a simple x, y and z angle based on axis angle representation". An axis-angle representation, as the name suggests, specifies _one_ axis and _one_ angle. You could have a _rotation vector_ with $x,y,x$ coordinates, but I wouldn't call them angles. So it is unclear to me what your tool is providing. I am beginning to suspect it is even possible that you have gotten the terms for rotations confused and your tool actually is giving you Euler angles after all.